# В русском есть глагол "измождать"?! Я не нашла

Tags: выбор-слов

**[Измождать](http://russian_ukrainian.academic.ru/129430/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)**

> -ся, измождить, -ся виснажувати, -ся и виснажати, -ся, виснажити, -ся, знесилювати, -ся, знесилити, -ся, зморювати, -ся, зморити, -ся; срвн.
>   Изнурять, Истощать. Измождённый - виснажений, знесилений, зморений,
>   нужденний, натруджений, тлінний. [Мати лежала на лаві, її спокійне
>   нужденне обличчя… (М. Лев.). Вона приходила в свою кімнату така
>   втомлена, аж тлінна (Н.-Лев.)].
>
> Русско-украинский словарь. 2013.

А у меня:

> Хороший quest-house – это частный дом, не нарушающий ландшафта,
>   погружённый в дикую природу, но со всеми мыслимыми удобствами.
>   Отдельные комнаты, иногда даже крошечные виллы, и – что всякий раз
>   удивляет – настоящая ванна. Лучше, чтобы в таком доме был и бассейн.
>   **Африканская жара измождает.** А во всю стену – окно, с видом. Правда, во время утреннего туалета на тебя беззастенчиво пялятся
>   какие-то свинки, не знаю даже их названия, и наглые попугаи.

Одарите глаголом!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово есть, это старославянизм, Вы же чувствуете: -жд-.

Слово редкое, но используется иногда как синоним "изнурить".

По Далю, в русском варианте звучит иначе: *измодеть*;

остался в диалектах:

**ИЗМОДЕТЬ** вологодск. измождаться, исхудать, исчахнуть, изныть, истаять, исчавреть. Измодел парень вовсе, знать испортили его. Лед на озере измодел на месте. Измоде́лый измодевший.И́змодень ж. хиль, хилость, вялость, слабость, дряхлость, бессилие; || м. сиб. растен. Leonurus lanatus, благовонная, гремячка, черная -, сибирская крапива. Измодень полевой, Myosotis palustris, незабудка, волосовая, горлянка. Измодик м. Polygala amara, см. истод.

Изможда́ть, изможди́ть кого, изнурять, истощать, мучить, морить лишеньями и трудами. изможда́ться,страдат. и возвр. по смыслу речи. Изможде́нье ср. оконч. действ. по знач. глаг. на ть и на ся.
http://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Dal-term-11157.htm

Сейчас используется только как причастие - *изможденный*.

Старославянское – *изъждень* (изнуренный, ослабленный).

В современном языке употребляется в значении «уставший, обессиленный». Слово имеет тот же корень, что и устаревшее «мозгнуть» – «портиться, гибнуть». В древнерусский язык прилагательное пришло из старославянского, изменив форму.

Производные: измождение, изможденность.

Этимологический словарь русского языка. М.: Русский язык от А до Я. Издательство <ЮНВЕС> Москва 2003

изможденный ср. мо́згнуть "портиться, гибнуть"; см. Преобр. I, 
266. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Answer (score 1):

[Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C): 1. изнурять, истомлять ◆ Я на всякой дряни измождать себя не намерен. Златовратский Н.Н., «Рассказы», 2013 г.

Answer (score 1):

**измождать** и **измозжать**
**1.** Сокрушать что. *Толщи их **измождить**.*
**2.** Изнурять, приводить в изнеможение, удручать. ***Измозжать*** плоть, тело постом, трудами.
[Общий церковно-славяно-российский словарь](https://books.google.ee/books?id=D9xDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1017&lpg=PA1017&dq=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=MNXHBeNoqT&sig=DpUJteoCp2nkd9h442qoYNHHbuM&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9-cis3JfTAhXmFZoKHTt6ArE4FBDoAQg5MAc#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)

*Отвечает нежить: "Иду...жилы мертвить, тела **измождать**, лепоту изменять, бесом мучить".*
[Энциклопедия сверхъестественных существ](https://books.google.ee/books?id=EbPSAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA449&lpg=PA449&dq=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=3js9Da0Wse&sig=fguKXM_UqL1PKPS1afk_gHAg7GY&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjeme7V2pfTAhWBC5oKHV82DGE4FBDoAQgmMAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)

*...она говорила: надобно **измождать** это лицо, которое я, вопреки заповеди Божией, часто раскрашивала румянами и белилами.*
[Иероним Стридонский, Сочинения](https://books.google.ee/books?id=hDtsCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA587&lpg=PA587&dq=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&source=bl&ots=83i_ZG8S4p&sig=HfUJwEb8cRAIzg7lFSTl3-5wD5Y&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVr8uw2pfTAhWIdpoKHSizDU44FBDoAQghMAI#v=onepage&q=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C&f=false)

*Ставить палки в колёса, **измождать** команды в спартанских условиях будет наш остроумный и весёлый Ведущий! Обещаем, жарко будет всем!*
[скалодром "Трапеция"](https://trapezia.by/command/)